# Conditions on $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\chi(\mathcal{F}) = 0$ for a coherent sheaf on a curve over $k$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a projective curve (you may also assume Cohen-Macaulayness) over some field $k$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Then the Euler-Poincare characteristic of $\mathcal{F}$ is equal to
$$
\chi(\mathcal{F}) = \dim_k H^0(X,\mathcal{F}) - \dim_k H^1(X,\mathcal{F}).
$$

> What are necessary and what are sufficient conditions on $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\chi(\mathcal{F}) = 0$?

Comment: Have you checked the case $X=\mathbb P^1, \mathcal F = \mathcal O(n), n \in \mathbb Z$?